# Installing a SSL certificate on a subdomain on Plesk 10

Tags: php, linux, apache, ssl

I'm having trouble installing a SSL certificate on a subdomain within Plesk 10.

I don't seem to have an option to add the SSL certificate to a subdomain only. If i add the cert to the base domain will the subdomain share the same certificate?

Has anyone managed to install a cert on a subdomain using plesk 10?

Comment: I have an SSL cert working on my main domain but I cannot get it working on a subdomain of the main domain.  They are telling me I need to buy a wildcard SSL.  Wish they had been honest with me while I was researching the windows host product.  They assured me the SSL would work with all Sub Domains off the main domain I applied the SSL cert to.  Is anyone else able to do this in Plesk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSL certificates affect all Connections made to the IP it is bound to, there is no way to bind a certificate to a subdomain or a specific folder because the SSL Setup has to be made before the URL is given to the server process.

You either need to use the same SSL certificate for all domains on your server or you need a new IP and use it only for the subdomain that needs to be protected. (I believe there was a SSL Configuration Link in IP management or something...)

Answer (score 0):

Multiple Certificates on a single IP **is** now possible using SNI:

http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP10/10.2.0/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-administrator-guide/index.htm?fileName=68308.htm

http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI